# How to concatenate bound property with a string for a Label content in WPF/XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

For a WPF app in XAML I have the following label:

```
<Label Content = "{Binding Path=myProprety}" x:Name="myLabel"></Label>
```

The label at the moment shows: 22 (Because myProprety is 22 now)

But I want to concatenate this binded property value with string "%" and obtain the label content as:

22%

I couldn't find an example how it is done or even if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `StringFormat` property:

```
<TextBlock Text ="{Binding Path=myProprety, StringFormat={}{0}%}" x:Name="myLabel" />
```

Or several `Run` elements:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding myProprety, Mode=OneTime}" /><Run Text="%" />
</TextBlock>
```

On a `Label`, you can use the `ContentStringFormat` property:

```
<Label Content ="{Binding Path=myProprety}" x:Name="myLabel"
       ContentStringFormat="{}{0}%" />
```

Comment: I use Label since data changes from 0% to 100%. This works on TextBlock only? If its the only option I can switch to that of course.

Comment: @pnatk: See my edit. There is a `ContentStringFormat` property that you can use on `Labels`.

Comment: Yes thank you, This is great answer with examples. It works now.